# Why is this Unity XML Configuration not resolving the types?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, app-config

I have the following Unity XML Configuration in my `unity.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
  <container>
    <register type="System.Net.WebProxy, System" name="webProxy">
      <constructor>
        <param name="Address" value="proxy.corporate.com:8080" type="System.String"/>
        <param name="BypassOnLocal" value="false" type="System.Boolean"/>
      </constructor>
    </register>
    <register type="System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler, System.Net.Http" name="proxyClientHandler">
      <property name="Proxy">
        <dependency name="webProxy"/>
      </property>
      <property name="PreAuthenticate" value="true"/>
      <property name="UseDefaultCredentials" value="false"/>
    </register>
    <register type="System.Net.Http.HttpClient, System.Net.Http">
      <constructor>
        <param name="handler">
          <dependency name="proxyClientHandler"/>
        </param>
      </constructor>
    </register>
  </container>
</unity>
```

The config file is correctly referenced from `app.config`. The assemblies for `System` and `System.Net.Http` are referenced in the project.

When I call `UnityContainer.LoadConfiguration()` in my code an exception is thrown:

> The type name or alias System.Net.WebProxy, System could not be
>   resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type
>   name.

The exact details for each type can be seen at the below links:

- [System.Net.WebProxy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234s6ee9(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193664(v=vs.118).aspx)

Why is this exception being thrown when the format for `type` is, as far as I'm aware (and has worked in other situations), `type="<fully qualified type name>, <assembly name>"`?

**Edit**:

Please note I've tried with and without adding the `", <assembly name>"` into the `type` value and the result was that the same exception was thrown for `HttpClientHandler` instead of `WebProxy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the `<namespace>` tag? [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660914%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#config_namespace)

There is also the syntax required for CLR types which I don't see in your XML. You could try that too. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660933%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx#_CLR_Type_Names) (Also, the docs state you need to supply things like the public key which I've never needed to do when specifying CLR types.)

Comment: I have not tried this (didn't know about it). I'll give it a go now.

Comment: This was it. Needed to use the fully qualified strong name for the assemblies. eg. `type="System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler, System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"`